# Rest service producing Strange response in Mule

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio

I have a following Mule flow :-

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
<jdbc-ee:query key="InsertQuery" value="INSERT INTO getData(ID,NAME,AGE,DESIGNATION)VALUES(#[flowVars['id']],#[flowVars['name']],#[flowVars['age']],#[sessionVars['valueFromgetDesc']])"/>          
</jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="ttFlow1" doc:name="ttFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="{"insertDataRequest": [{"id": "1","name": "Sidray","age": "55","designation": "SE"},{"id": "2","name": "Anir","age": "51","designation": "SE"}]}"/>

<jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
   <component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl"/>
</jersey:resources>

<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
 <foreach collection="#[message.payload.insertDataRequest]" doc:name="For Each">
    <logger message="INSERTDATA #[message.payload.id]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[message.payload.id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-variable variableName="name" value="#[message.payload.name]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-variable variableName="age" value="#[message.payload.age]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="designation" value="#[message.payload.designation]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
   <logger message="Total #[variable:id] #[variable:name] #[sessionVars['designation']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

 <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="InsertQuery" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_Global" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>

 <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
  <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
  <scripting:text>
  <![CDATA[ 
   import com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.*
   def dResponse = new DataResponse()
   dResponse.response='Data inserted Successfully'
   return dResponse]]>
  </scripting:text>
  </scripting:script> 
  </scripting:component> 

 <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
 <logger message="Data inserted Successfully" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   </foreach>
</flow>
```

Here what I am doing is I have the restImpl class ( `<component class="com.test.services.schema.maindata.v1.Impl.MainDataImpl"/>`) which is returning the request in the following format :-

`[insertDataRequest=[DataRequest [id=1, name=Sidray, age=21, designation=SE], DataRequest [id=2, name=Anir, age=55, designation=SE]]]`

Now after that I am using `json:json-to-object-transformer` to get all the value of from the request object like **id**,**name**,**age** and storing it in flow variable and then calling **JDBC** **outboundendpoint** and using these variables in **SQL** to insert data ..

I am able to insert into DB successfully ..  ..Then I am setting the response using **Groovy script**

Now the issue is simple .. Here I am able to call the rest service and insert into DB successfully .. but the issue is I am not able to display the response in browser after the service call ,..

[image]

Please help

Comment: It would be nice if you could format the XML because it's so hard to read as it is currently. Also, as I commented recently on a similar question, I think it's a wrong design to use a mix of Jersey component followed by other flow elements. Either use a simple component or move the rest of the flow in another flow and call it from within your JAX-RS annotated resource.

Comment: And the real question now: what do you want to respond over HTTP? The `foreach` will produce multiple values: how do you intend to aggregate them to create a response that is serializable over HTTP? Again, if the JAX-RS component would be the only one in this flow, that would be much easier because the response building would be done right in the component instead of the clunky mixed-mode you have here.

Comment: David, I want to set the response in Json format generating by the Groovy

Comment: This Groovy script will be called N-times by the for-each loop: you need to have an aggregation strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `foreach` doc: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Foreach

> When you split certain collection types — Java, for example — into many pieces for processing, the collection may be re-aggregated into a different collection type — MuleMessageCollection, for example. (As a result, you may need to add extra flow steps to transform the processed message collection back into its original collection type.)

So with `foreach`, you will not receive an aggregation of the result of each execution of what's inside of it, thus you'' have to aggregate yourself.

I suggest the following:

- Create a flow variable before the foreach of type List
- In the foreach, append your results to this List
- After for foreach convert the List into whatever response you want to send to the browser.

Or drop the foreach and just use a regular `collection-splitter` followed by an `aggregator` :)

Answer (score 1):

So, finally as per David's solution, created the flow variable and appended the result within the for and outside the for each ... able to set the flow variable in payload and able to display it